# SceneKit SCNAnimation: How to check if a certain animation is currently playing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, scenekit

I have an animated human like character (from a DAE file) with a lot of individual animation files (also DAE). I am using SCNAnimationPlayer.

Everything is well setup and plays as expected.

When applying a new animation, the old animation is morphed into the new animation with no issue.

But when I apply the exact same animation, which is currently running on the charactes, i.Ex some random Idle animation, the animation replaces itself and then the character gets a small **hick-up**, the animation cannot be blended well into itself.

**So I asked myself: Is there an (easy) way to check if the new animation (choosed randomly) is the old one, **which is currently** playing? And then NOT start the animation over the existing.**

My idea is to implement something like this (pseudocode):

```
guard !(node.animationPlayer(forKey: "newanimkey").isPlaying) else { return }
```

*(`isPlaying` does NOT exist - but there is a `paused` property, but it **defaults** to false, you have to explicitly pause the animation to get it true...)*

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I need to not start a new animation if the old one has been canceled (it cancels automatically if anything else modifies the animated property)

Comment: Finally I did a workaround by saving the actual animation that is loaded into a new variable. Then I check this variable for the next runloop, and so I can prevent to load the same animation over itself (it just loads another one). Not state of the art, but it works.

Comment: Yeah, I do that too for something a little more complicated, but the gist is the same. I just don’t like having to remember keeping that variable updated from various places

Comment: I fully agree. I don't understand why apple has no proper solution to this. It should be no effort for them to easely check if the animation is really currently playing... I don't get it.

Comment: I guess they need to strike a balance between utility and performance.